# C++ Pseudo-RSA solving for d (decryption key) quickly with large numbers

Tags: c++, algorithm, cryptography, rsa, modulo

```
for(d = 0;; d++)
{
    if((d * e) % tn == 1)
        break;
}
```

the following code is used on my RSA program to find the value for the d variable which will be used as the decryption key (d, N)
so far when dealing with large numbers, this function takes quiet a while to cycle. I was wondering if there is a faster algorithm for this because modulo with large integers is always slow.

for example if the e value was 8161 and the tn value was 656316480 then it would take more than 4 seconds to fully calculate for d. The program works correctly, it's just that this part is very slow.

I've tried using the Extended Euclidean algorithm to calculate for d but for some reason it always gives me trouble.

```
uint64_t extended_gcd(uint64_t a, uint64_t b)
{
uint64_t x = 0, lastx = 1, y = 1, lasty = 0, temp, quotient;
    while(b != 0)
    {
        temp = b;
        quotient = a / b;
        b = a % b;
        a = temp;
        temp = x;
        x = lastx - quotient * x;
        lastx = temp;
        temp = y;
        y = lasty - quotient * y;
        lasty = temp;
   }
   return lasty;
}
```

Bundled with;

```
d = extended_gcd(tn, e)
if(d < 0) //d CAN be negative
    d += tn;
```

Ive copied the above function (extended_gcd) from an old forum post I saw when I searched and it does in fact work, but only with small numbers. When the numbers get too extreme the return value is unexpectedly big, messing up the whole decryption key. Im not sure where exactly the problem is and I cant find a reliable function elsewhere with the same algorithm. Like I said I want to find a better algorithm for the first for loop Ive posted but I'm all out of ideas.

Comment: If it were possible, RSA would be broken (and either everyone would know or absolutely no one).

Comment: @ElliottFrisch so you're telling me that there is nothing I can do to make it faster?

Comment: Good grief. I hope not : )

Comment: @nurtul Right. Maybe you can optimize some tiny bits here and there, but nothing significant for large numbers.

Comment: Yeah, you are trying to solve the hard problem that's behind the security of RSA. Both d and N are part of the public key, so you are trying to calculate the private key from the public key. You may want to take a look into RSA key generation to see how RSA key pairs are generated instead.

Comment: So essentially what I'm doing here is cracking my own RSA... I'll look into key pair generation haha @MaartenBodewes-owlstead

Comment: Yeah you got it now. You are at 4 seconds for ~32 bit, not too shabby but not record breaking either :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem you are running into is: your integers are too small and will overflow when the values get larger ...

fixed size integers for things like RSA ... no good idea unless you happen to have integers with a few thousand bits length... instead of normal ints or even uint64_t, try an arbitrary precision integer library like GMP ...

your extended_gcd looks right ... it's the extended euclidean algorithm and should work for real world RSA key generation

Comment: that makes sense I'll also look into this

Answer (score 1):

Alright I found an answer that solved my problems. The following function is the modular inverse which is apparently a modified Extended Euclidean Algorithm and it solves correctly.

```
uint64_t modinv(uint64_t u, uint64_t v)
{
    uint64_t inv, u1, u3, v1, v3, t1, t3, q;
    int64_t iter;
    u1 = 1;
    u3 = u;
    v1 = 0;
    v3 = v;
    iter = 1;
    while(v3 != 0)
    {
        q = u3 / v3;
        t3 = u3 % v3;
        t1 = u1 + q * v1;
        u1 = v1;
        v1 = t1;
        u3 = v3;
        v3 = t3;
        iter = -iter;
    }
    if(u3 != 1)
        return  0;
    if(iter < 0)
        inv = v - u1;
    else
        inv = u1;
    return inv;
}
```

where "u" is set equal to "e" and "v" is set equal to "tn"

Example

```
P = 31
Q = 7
TN = (P - 1) * (Q - 1) = 180
N = P * Q = 217
E = 1 < E < TN and coprime with N so... 53
D = Calculated using function above... 17

Value to be encrypted with public key (E, N) = 32
32^(E) % N = 32^7 % 217 = 156
Value to be decrypted with private key (D, N) = 156
156^(D) % N = 156^17 % 217 = 32
```

I assume above math has been done correctly because it's a straight copy paste from my program. And I tried it with larger numbers, a prime reaching ~90000 and the result was instant and correct. I hope I am not deceived by something here.